# Expressing rotational energy levels in temperature units

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

Let's say we have a molecule whose energy levels can be expressed as $E_r = B J(J+1)$ where $B$ is the rotational constant and J is the rotational quantum number. I've seen everywhere in the literature that these energy levels are often expressed in units of energy, frequency, and wavelength... but also in temperature. I see [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Rotational_Spectroscopy/Rotational_Spectroscopy_of_Diatomic_Molecules) that $B$ can be defined for the energy to be expressed in energy units ($B$) or wavelength/frequency ($\bar{B}$) units. If I have a constant such that $[B] = \text{cm}^{-1}$, how can I obtain the energy levels expressed in Kelvin?

I tried multiplying both sides by $1/k$ ($k$ as in Boltzmann's constant), which would result in $$\frac{E_r}{k} = \frac{B}{k} J (J+1),$$ but for a "reasonable" value of $B=3\text{cm}^{-1}$ (based on the values given for O [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy)) I obtain temperatures with orders of magnitude of 23 and beyond for $J=0$ to $J=10$ (Oxygen would never get excited).

I was given a hint that I should use $h c / k$ to make the conversion to temperature. If I define a rotational constant such that $B' = hc/k B$, I do get reasonable values in Kelvin (in the order of tenths to hundreds), but I don't understand the reasoning behind that multiplication. Is that approach correct, and if so, what's the scientific logic behind it?

Comment: hc is the way to convert wavelength units to energy units, and then Boltzmann's constant converts between energy units and temperature units. Hence, the combination is the correct one. There is not much reasoning, to be honest. It is just annoying that we are not using natural units, whereby all of these are one and the same.